# Cannot run commands with 'no-ff' ( "fatal: '-no-ff' does not appear to be a git repository" )

Tags: git

When pushing or pulling I can't seem to perform commands with the -no-ff option, whereas without, it is fine. It's been Ok previously, so can't think why these errors have started

```
git pull -no-ff origin ticket_1076
```

gives the error

```
fatal: '-no-ff' does not appear to be a git repository

Warning: Your console font probably doesn't support Unicode. If you     experience strange characters in the output, consider switching to a     TrueType font such as Consolas!
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

```
git pull origin ticket_1076
```

works fine..

I'm not sure what to try - I've read some other topics regarding "does not appear to be a git repository" but it does seems like my local and remote repositories are synced properly. I'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass a double `-`, so: `--no-ff` for it to work.

Otherwise the option is not recognized and used as the first parameter, being `<repository>` and which it does not recognize as a repository.

Comment: i did try that actually but I get ```error: unknown non-ascii option in string: `--no-ff'
usage: git pull [<options>] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]``` then a list of allowed commands, --no-ff is not amongst them

Comment: I assume that you are running with some form of `international` keyboard turned on. Please disable that, so that your `--` does not turn into `—`

Comment: yep, something must have changed in my environment, but the correct dash does work. Thanks for helping me narrow it down